# How to solve Type error in an ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

How can I solve this error:

> core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'slug' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'slug' of undefined

My code:

```
this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products?filter[category]=" + this.category.slug).then((data) =>{
  console.log(JSON.parse(data.body));
```

Comment: generally this is caused by pointing to a variable or part of an object that is indeed `undefined`. often this is a time-frame issue. Say at init of the view you say `myObject.myArray[0].slug` in any sort of setting: eval, new var hydration, pointer hydration, anything, whilst the object in question is just an empty unhydrated var until your `mySetVariableFunc()` is called and in this case it happens to be triggered by an observable which itself is triggered after the init. Then it will always send back an error relating to how a member is `undefined`
I can't promise that that's what you have

Comment: please check the code which I have mentioned above please @tatsu.

Answer (score 1):

well to me this confirms what I first said. you are indeed pointing to a child of an object within an observable (whether you know what observables are or not) (observables sometimes move all the way up the priority list and happen before hydration of any other var).

so here's the precautions I like to take to make sure things don't go badly: splitting things up.

Also, here's a "hack" I like to use on a general basis in order to ensure I can continue my dev cycle unhindered and have a better notion of where things are failing other than just "undefined":

```
this.category['slug'];
```

> I never go this far but this is also allowed : 
>  `this['category']['slug'];`

see this is different because it will actually return the undefined instead of failing there at a JS level.

now to me it seems pretty obvious that you need to ascertain `this.category.slug`  in the instant it's being evaluated isn't in a state in it's lifeline prior to it's initialization :

```
var myFunctionToLogSlug = () => { //here you could pass this.category.slug as an arg but
//that's the same as simply calling in within the body of this method because your
//context (this) is the same, ergo the pointer and timeframe are also the same.
  console.log("is this.category.slug empty ? : ", this.category.slug);
  return this.category.slug;
};

this.WooCommerce.getAsync(
   "products?filter[category]=" + myFunctionToLogSlug()).then(data =>{
       console.log(JSON.parse(data.body));
});
```

once you've ascertained `this.category.slug` is indeed undefined at the point it is called, you can either move `this.WooCommerce.getAsync` to a time-place you know `this.category.slug` to be defined, or move `this.category.slug`'s hydration to the inside of the `getAsync`.

hope this helps ! :)